# Как обратиться к элементам массива БЕЗ применения индексов

Tags: c++

Имеется динамический массив. Цель работы написать такую же программу, но без применения индексов для обращения к элементам динамических массивов. Далее приводиться пример программы где использованы индексы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");

    int num; 
    int a, b, count = 0;

    cout << ("Введите количество элементов: ");
    cin >> num;

    int *p = new int[num]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cin >> p[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if ((p[i] > 0 && p[i + 1] > 0) || (p[i] < 0 && p[i + 1] < 0) && (abs(p[i]) < abs(p[i + 1]))) count++;

        p[i] = p[i + 1];

        }

    cout << "Ответ: " << count << endl;

    delete[] p; 

    system("pause");


      return 0;
}
```

**Цель же самой программы была простая задача из курса обучения по программированию**

> Даны натуральное число п, действительные числа а1 ..., an. В последовательности
> а1 ..., an определить число соседств двух чисел одного знака, причем
> модуль первого числа должен быть меньше модуля второго числа.

Comment: в этой задаче массив вообще не нужен, надо только сравнивать текущий элемент с предыдущим

Comment: `p[i]` записывайте как `*(p+i)`...

Answer (score 1):

```
int num, count = 0;   
cin >> num;
int* p = new int[num];
for (int* i = p; i !=p + num; i++)    
    cin >> *i;    

for (int* ptr1 = p, *ptr2 = p + 1; ptr2 != p + num; ++ptr1, ++ptr2)          
    if (*ptr1 * *ptr2 > 0 && abs(*ptr1) < abs(*ptr2))
        ++count;
cout << "Ответ: " << count << endl;
delete[] p;
```

P.S. Не уверен, но думаю, современный компилятор даже не выполнит умножение *ptr1 * *ptr2, для проверки на положительность. При одинаковых знаках, сразу определит, что условие истина. Хотелось бы слушать мнение гуру...

Comment: Я упростил до функции  `int f(int *p1, int *p2) {return *p1 * *p2 > 0 ? 1 : 0;}` и компилировал с несколькими ключами оптимизации. `gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0`  честно умножает / Не знают авторы компайлера таких приемов программирования -) / Достаточно было бы сделать xor и сдвинуть на 31 разряд / Поколение пепси ... Канула культура оптимизации

Comment: Кстати, для `return *p1 * *p2 < 0 ? 1 : 0;` они все равно умножают (!), но потом все же сдвигают (почти хорошо -))